# Expectation of the number of points inside a foursquare of a rectangle

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation, random

Consider a rectangle (black one) in the following image. Lets take four *random* points uniformly on each border then connecting the points one after another (red lines) to get a foursquare  inside the rectangle.

[image]

If we put a set of **random** points ($n$ points) uniformly  inside the rectangle , I would like to know what is the mathematical expectation of the number of points that are inside the red area?

Since the position of red points are random, I really can't solve this problem.

The probability that each point falls in the red area, is the area of red_line divided by area of rectangle. Since the area it self is a random process, so we need to calculate the expectation of the area of the red line.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The expected number should be $n\times\frac{Q}{R}$ where $Q$ is the area of the "foursquare" and $R$ is the area if the  rectangle

Comment: The expected number of points is just $n$ times the ratio of area of the red quadrilateral to the area of the full rectangle.

Comment: what is $Q$? the area of red quadrilateral

Comment: The expected number is proportional to the expected area of the foursquare
which in terms equals to the difference of the area of rectangle and the sum of expected areas of 4 triangles. For each triangle, the two sides (around the right angle) are independent, so its area is $\frac12 \times\left( \frac12 \right)^2 = \frac18$ of that of the rectangle.
This means the expected number is simply $n (1 - 4\times \frac18) = \frac12 n$.

Comment: @achille hui: I don't see the independence.

Comment: @quasi The vertices of the foursquare are "four random points uniformly on each other". Even though the sides of triangles at different corners are not independent, the two sides of any triangle are independent.

Comment: @achille hui: But once two adjacent red vertices are chosen, the areas of the other three right triangles are not independent of the two chosen red vertices.

Comment: @quasi expectation of sum of something = sum of expectation of something even when the items involved are not independent.

Comment: @achille hui: Ok, I got it -- thanks.

Comment: @achillehui Your solution seems right, I would be appreciated if you provide more details

Comment: @quasi I want to accept its answer

Comment: But now I'm not so sure about the initial concept. For $n$ randomly chosen points in the rectangle, why is the expected number of the $n$ points inside the red quadrilateral the same as $n$ times the expected ratio of area of the red quadrilateral to the area of the rectangle?

Comment: @quasi: the probability of falling inside the quadrilateral is its relative area.

Comment: @Yves Daoust: Yes, I know that, but my question is why can we use the expected value of the ratio?

Comment: @qausi expected[ number in ] = expected[ 1st in ] + expected [2nd in] + ... = n expected[ 1st in ] = n prob [ 1st in ] = n area[foursquare]/area[rectangle].

Comment: @quasi: because the coordinates of the random points and those of the quadrilateral vertices are independent. Then you are averaging on all points inside the rectangle, giving a ratio, and all possible quadrilaterals, giving the expectation of the ratio.

Comment: @quasi If you flip 10 coins, how many do you expect to be heads? $10(\frac{1}{2})$. Same here. Each placement of a random point in the rectangle is a Bernoulli trial. Multiple placements will result in a Binomial distribution. And so, $E(X)=np$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution

Comment: @$\{\text{achille hui,Yves Daoust,Shuri2060}\}$: Those replies don't target my misunderstanding. Take the the case $n=1$. I agree that the expected area of the red quadrilateral is $1/2$ the area of the rectangle. Are you claiming that the probability that a random point of the rectangle falls within the red quadrilateral is $1/2$? I don't see that.

Comment: @Shuri2060: Still missing my confusion. If the red quadrilateral had area exactly $1/2$ of the area of the rectangle, then the probability that a random point of the rectangle falls within the red quadrilateral would be 1/2. Sure, that's fine. But all you have is an expected ratio of $1/2$, and the ratios themselves are subject to a probability distribution.

Comment: @all: Probability is a tricky business!

Comment: Back to my confusion: I agree that the expected value of the area ratio is $1/2$. But are the area ratios themselves uniformly distributed?

Comment: @quasi: That doesn't matter. Once we know what the expected area is, that is clearly also the probability that a randomly selected point fall inside a randomly selected quadrilateral.

Comment: @Henning Makholm: It's the "clearly" that I don't see.

Comment: @Yves Daoust: So the first two comments in this thread (the one by Jonathan Davidson and the one by me) were correct in a "lucky" sense, since the justification requires verifying the symmetry of the actual (non-uniform) distribution of area ratios.

Comment: @quasi: I have addressed that. The ratios are distributed as the product of two triangular random variables, plus $1/2$. This distribution is symmetric around $1/2$.

Comment: @quasi: no, the computation requires the evaluation of the expectation, be the distribution symmetric or not. (Symmetry making it trivial.)

Comment: @Shuri2060: I understand that the expected area ratio is $1/2$. My concern is why you can just use that expected value as if it was just one quadriulateral, when computing the probability of landing in a randomly chosen red quadrilateral. This was addressed by Yves Daoust, and I accept his explanation, but was glossed over by others.

Comment: Ok, never mind -- I get it. Sorry for my confusion. Thanks to all.

Comment: @quasi Although vague, I think the idea I present in the previous comment shows why. The probability is computed by taking the expected probability of each individual quadrilateral case. This is $E(p)=E\left(\frac{\textrm{Area of quad}}{\textrm{Area of Rect}}\right)=\frac{E\left({\textrm{Area of quad}}\right)}{{\textrm{Area of Rect}}}$

Comment: Yes, I see it now -- thanks. A mental block I guess.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

WLOG, I am solving for a unit square.

Let the four vertices be at coordinates $x,x',y,y'$ on the respective sides. The area of the quadrilateral is $1$ minus the areas of the four corners,

$$A=1-\frac{xy+(1-x)y'+x'(1-y)+(1-x')(1-y')}2=\frac{1-(x-x')(y-y')}2.$$

As $x,x',y,y'$ are uniform independent random variables, their pairwise differences follow independent triangular distributions centered on $0$, and the expectation of the product is the product of the expectations.

Hence, $$E(A)=\frac12.$$

Answer (score 9):

One way of doing it:

---

Let the vertices of the rectangle be $(0,0),(w, 0),(0, h),(w, h)$.

Then the $4$ red points are $(0, r_1h),(w, r_2h), (r_3w,0), (r_4w,h)$ where $r_n$ are uniformly distributed random numbers between $0$ and $1$.

The area of a particular quadrilateral is

$$\textrm{Area of rectangle} - \textrm{Area of 4 triangles}=hw\left(1-\frac{1}{2}(r_1r_3+r_2(1-r_3)+(1-r_1)r_4+(1-r_4)(1-r_2))\right)$$

$$=hw\left(1-\frac{1}{2}(r_1r_3+r_2-r_2r_3+r_4-r_1r_4+1-r_2-r_4+r_2r_4)\right)$$

$$=hw\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}(r_1r_3-r_2r_3-r_1r_4+r_2r_4)\right)$$

$$=hw\left(\frac{1}{2}(1-(r_1-r_2)(r_3-r_4))\right)$$

The expected number of points inside a particular quadrilateral is $n\left(\frac{\textrm{Area of quadrilateral}}{\textrm{Area of rectangle}}\right)$

We then want to integrate between $0$ and $1$ for each $r_n$ to find the final expectation which gives us:

$$E(\textrm{Number of Points})=\int^1_0\int^1_0\int^1_0\int^1_0{n\left(\frac{\textrm{Area of quadrilateral}}{\textrm{Area of rectangle}}\right)\,\,\,dr_1dr_2dr_3dr_4}$$

$$=\frac{n}{2}-\frac{n}{2}\int^1_0\int^1_0\int^1_0\int^1_0{(r_1-r_2)(r_3-r_4)\,\,\,dr_1dr_2dr_3dr_4}$$

$$=\frac{n}{2}-\frac{n}{2}\int^1_0\int^1_0\left(\int^1_0r_1\,\,\,dr_1-\int^1_0r_2\,\,\,dr_2\right)(r_3-r_4)\,\,\,dr_3dr_4$$

$$=\frac{n}{2}$$

Comment: So what is the answer in the end?! what fraction of $n$ are inside?

Comment: Could someone verify my answer? Intuitively, I find $\frac{n}{2}$ confusing.

Comment: @Shuri2060 what's so confusing, it is the correct answer.

Comment: @achillehui Might be me, but I can think of quadrilaterals which take up more than half the area of the rectangle, but not less than.

Comment: @achillehui ahaha - yes, definitely me. Let 2 of them be close to $(0,0)$ and let the other 2 be close to $(w,h)$. nvm about that

Comment: +1 I'm glad you figure it out yourself. Following is something that should make the answer more intuitive. First fix 3 vertices and vary one of the vertices, say $r_1$. The area of the the foursquare has the form const $r_1$ + const. When one take expectation over $r_1$, the expected area is the same as if you set $r_1$ directly at the midpoint. Do the same thing to other 3 vertices. one find the expected area of foursquare is the same as the rhombus having the midpoints of the edges of rectangle as vertices. i.e. one half of that of the rectangle.